# External creation for PGFPlots doesn't work

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I've been facing memory problems due to a high amount of data for plots created with `pgfplots`. Thus I wanted to use the external mode but no usable file can be created.

Here is my Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside, fleqn, ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18]
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
        \input{plot.tikz}
    \caption{...}
    \label{fig:a}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This is the file `plot.tikz` which is included:

```
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,1.00000,1.00000}% is used for other addplots not shown

\begin{tikzpicture} 

\begin{axis}[% 
width=5cm, 
height=5cm, 
at={(0.758in,0.481in)}, 
scale only axis, 
xmin=-1, 
xmax=1, 
xlabel style={font=\bfseries}, 
xlabel={Real z}, 
ymin=-1, 
ymax=1, 
ylabel style={font=\bfseries}, 
ylabel={Imag z}, 
axis background/.style={fill=white} 
] 
\addplot [color=black,solid,line width=1.5pt,forget plot] 
  table[row sep=crcr]{% 
0.52    0.67\\ 
0.82    0.67\\ 
}; 

\addplot [color=black,solid,line width=1.5pt,forget plot] 
  table[row sep=crcr]{% 
0.52    -0.67\\ 
0.82    -0.67\\ 
}; 

%% Several other \addplot's 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

This Code gives me the following error:

> ```
> ! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -halt-on-error
>     -interaction=batchmode -jobname "test_pgf-figure0"
>     "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{test_pgf}\input{test_pgf}"'
> did NOT result in a usable output file 'test_pgf-figure0'
> (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled
> system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is
> also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply
> failed? Error messages can be found in 'test_pgf-figure0.log'. If you continue
> now, I'll try to typeset the picture.
> ```

The mentioned `test_pgf-figure0.log` file is not created as well.

I read a solution, that mentions compiling every file manually, but I need approximately 30 or more figures that might change in the future. Thus I don't want to to that over and over again.

Comment: Welcome! Try removing underscores from filenames and using hyphens instead.

Comment: @thewaywewalk That seems rather unlikely to me.

Comment: Are you compiling the document with shell escape enabled? Are you sure the command being issued by TikZ is correct for your system?

Comment: Removing the underscores leads to the same error message. I tried adding the line "-enable-write18" to the command line of the latex compiler and I tried using "\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18]" as well as "\tikzexternalize" in the preamble in every imaginable combination. Same error message over and over again. What i do now is compiling every single image manually and adding the pdf image...

Comment: Does externalisation work for you with a minimal TikZ picture or does it fail regardless? What does the log file for the image say?